# How to store Firebase data in array and print them out?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had been trying to store firebase data into an array and print them out all day long, but to no avail. I will really appreciate help from the community.

Below is an image of how the current firebase database looks like:

[image]

Below is the code of how the function to read data from firebase looks like:

```
- (void)readDataFromServer {

_ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

_hotelRef = [_ref child:@"hotel bookings"];

NSString *userID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;

FIRDatabaseQuery *userHotelBookingsQuery = [[_hotelRef child:userID] queryOrderedByChild:@"number"];

[userHotelBookingsQuery observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.value == [NSNull null]) {

        NSLog(@"No messages");

    } else {

    [self.arrayOfBookingDetail removeAllObjects];

    self.arrayOfBookingDetail = (snapshot.value);

    NSString *firstMessage = [self.arrayOfBookingDetail objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"First message is: %@", firstMessage);

    }


 }];

}
```

Comment: add code to your question instead of image!

Comment: you want to read data or write data???? your function is about read data ... so what you want basically

Comment: apology, I didn't know the community favour actual code over image. I will do the changes. I will want to read the data, insert into an array, and display them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because you are getting the child by the user `uid` which do not actually exist. The `K2xxxxxxxx` are a unique string for each element and do not correspond to the user id. Try this

```
_ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

_hotelRef = [_ref child:@"hotel bookings"];

FIRDatabaseQuery *userHotelBookingsQuery = [_hotelRef queryOrderedByChild:@"number"];

[userHotelBookingsQuery observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.value == [NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"No messages");
    } else {
      //[self.arrayOfBookingDetail removeAllObjects];
      //self.arrayOfBookingDetail = (snapshot.children);
      //NSString *firstMessage = [self.arrayOfBookingDetail objectAtIndex:0];
      //NSLog(@"First message is: %@", firstMessage);
      NSDictionary *allUsersData = (NSDictionary*)snapshot.value;
      for (NSString *key in allUsersData.allKeys) {
           NSLog("@key is %@, data is %@",key,allUsersData[key]);
      }
    }

 }];

}
```

Edit :

To query for a **particular user** - change your query to

```
 FIRDatabaseQuery *userHotelBookingsQuery = [[_hotelRef queryOrderedByChild:@"userID"] queryEqualToValue:@"GEmxxxxxxxxx"];
```

Comment: I see. In the database image above, it shows a list of hotel bookings by various users. I wanted to query for all hotel bookings by a particular user.

Comment: I tried running the code you gave, the NSLog is returning "First Message is: Null". which i am not sure why.

Comment: thanks. In my logic flow, I will not know which user will be login. Which is why I used NSString *userID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid; to retrieve current login user, the return his/her hotel bookings record.

Comment: did not get that ? please explain more.

Comment: I don't think is it wise to hardcode the user ID @"GEmxxxxxxxxxx" in.

Comment: yes, i just added for example. you can replace that with current logged in user `uid`